# Colorzilla for IE9

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-9

Hi I've been trying to build a website and for my menu bar i've been using Colorzilla. It works fine in Chrome and Firefox but it the color is different in IE9. I realized that Colorzilla tells me to add the code with the folloing instructions:

> Add a "gradient" class to all your elements that have a gradient, and add the following override to your HTML to complete the IE9 support:

```
<!--[if gte IE 9]>
  <style type="text/css">
    .gradient {
       filter: none;
    }
  </style>
<![endif]-->
```

I'm kind of new to web design so I'm not sure where to add it. Can someone help me? I have a main.css with the following code.

```
#top_menu{

font: bold 16px Verdana;
text-align: center;
height: 20%;
border: 1px solid black;
color: 000000;
box-pack:center;
border-radius:10px;
box-shadow: rgba(110,110,100, .4) 10px 10px 10px;
-webkit-box-pack:center;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-box-shadow: rgba(110,110,110, .4) 10px 10px 10px ;
-webkit-box-align: stretch;
background: #b4e391; /* Old browsers */
/* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiA/Pgo8c3ZnIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIgd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwJSIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDEgMSIgcHJlc2VydmVBc3BlY3RSYXRpbz0ibm9uZSI+CiAgPGxpbmVhckdyYWRpZW50IGlkPSJncmFkLXVjZ2ctZ2VuZXJhdGVkIiBncmFkaWVudFVuaXRzPSJ1c2VyU3BhY2VPblVzZSIgeDE9IjAlIiB5MT0iMCUiIHgyPSIwJSIgeTI9IjEwMCUiPgogICAgPHN0b3Agb2Zmc2V0PSIwJSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iI2I0ZTM5MSIgc3RvcC1vcGFjaXR5PSIxIi8+CiAgICA8c3RvcCBvZmZzZXQ9IjUwJSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iIzYxYzQxOSIgc3RvcC1vcGFjaXR5PSIxIi8+CiAgICA8c3RvcCBvZmZzZXQ9IjEwMCUiIHN0b3AtY29sb3I9IiNiNGUzOTEiIHN0b3Atb3BhY2l0eT0iMSIvPgogIDwvbGluZWFyR3JhZGllbnQ+CiAgPHJlY3QgeD0iMCIgeT0iMCIgd2lkdGg9IjEiIGhlaWdodD0iMSIgZmlsbD0idXJsKCNncmFkLXVjZ2ctZ2VuZXJhdGVkKSIgLz4KPC9zdmc+);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #b4e391 0%, #61c419 50%, #b4e391 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#b4e391), color-stop(50%,#61c419), color-stop(100%,#b4e391)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #b4e391 0%,#61c419 50%,#b4e391 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #b4e391 0%,#61c419 50%,#b4e391 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #b4e391 0%,#61c419 50%,#b4e391 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #b4e391 0%,#61c419 50%,#b4e391 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#b4e391', endColorstr='#b4e391',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */

}
```

and then from my index.html i have a menu as follow:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <meta  charset="UTF-8">
        <head>
            <title>Welcome</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
        </head>

        <body>
            <nav id="top_menu">

                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></
                    <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact-us.html">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </body>
    </html>
```

I would appreciate if someone could help me out pointing out where that code has to be because I'm very confused. I don't have classes I only have id, and I don't know if I have to put it in the main.css or in the index.html
Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this just after  `<!DOCTYPE html>`:

```
<!--[if gte IE 9]>
  <style type="text/css">
    #top_menu {
       filter: none;
    }
  </style>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: When I run it (I'm using Notepad++) it tells me: "Internet Explorer restricted this webpage from running scripts or ActiveX controls". I click "Allow blocked content" and it goes back to the bad color that i don't want. When I upload it to my host it still gives me the different color in internet explorer.

Comment: Got a link to the site so I can check it out? It's very strange that that code would create that message.